# .Net - Accessing GPS Data from Plethora of Devices

Tags: .net, web, mobile, gps

Is anyone aware of any utility that can retrieve GPS data from other devices?  Such as handhelds, mobile phones, etc.

I'm building an website where we want users to be able to easily import various GPS coordinates that they may have collected - be it with a handheld gps by Garmin, Lowrance, etc or a mobile phone (android, iphone, xyz)  I know my Garmin came with software - but it was overkill - and requires the owner to read-up and figure it out.

I'm sure my Dad can plot points and markers on his GPS - but figuring out how to easily get that data out (exporting) to import may be overly-complicated.  So I'm looking to see if there's anyway to bridge that gap.

can anyone help shed some light as to how to attack this issue?  Is there any software available that's achieved something similar?

I'm developing in C# - and have seen that Garmin has a nice API - but other's don't - and not sure how exactly to interact with Phones.

Comment: I should also state - the only info I'm looking to get is the Lat/Lon and the DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most GPS devices with an output (serial, USB, etc...) will output NMEA sentences (http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#nmea).`

Comment: thanks - I found other info such as http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/ connecting to the serial ports and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287464/read-nmea-sentences-from-gps reading the NMEA as you suggested